# If statement to check the number of characters in a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

when the user adds a contact, it checks to see if the "character" count is 8, then it check the database to see if the username and the NewContact already exist, and if it "false", it inserts the new contact.
the bit that doesn't work is limiting the number of characters to 8

```
if (intval($s_id) == 8)
     {
        $db = mysql_connect("at-web2.xxx", "user_xxx", "xxxx");
        mysql_select_db("db_xxx",$db);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE u_id='$username' and c_id='$s_id'",$db);

        $myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);


        if(!$myrow)
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts(u_id,  c_id) VALUES ('$username','$s_id')",$db);

            header("Contact Added");
        }
        else
        {

            header("Contact Already Exist");
        }
    }
else
    {
         header("Incomplete Contact");

    }
```

Comment: Use strlen instead of intval.

Comment: Instead of a none standard header() message I would reccomend to return the status 200 and 404.

Comment: Umm... Is this question tagged jQuery? Posted code doesn't have that.

Comment: yeah but someone with jquery knowledge can solve this qstion innit

Answer (score 4):

You need [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function.

```
if(strlen($s_id) == 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `strlen` to get number of characters

```
 if (intval($s_id) == 8)
```

should be

```
if (strlen($s_id) == 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `strlen` with `trim` function to get accurate length of string.

```
if(strlen(trim($s_id)) == 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strlen (stringlength) predefined php function for getting the exact length of the string .

```
if(strlen($string) == 8)
{

//Statements

}
else
{
  //statements
}
```